# how to automatically close mobile select box when an option change event is fired?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile

Testing on Android 4.0.2 if I open a select menu and pick an option the change event fires ok but I have to click the done button of the menu to close the it. Is it possible to trigger this when an option has been selected? so far I've tried adding `.focus()` and `.blur()` to the body to shift focus but with no success.

This is the snippet of code I've been testing:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){ 
    console.log( $(this).find("option:selected").data('id') ); 

    $('body').blur();
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Also jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dnRZc/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it worked for me.

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){ 
   $(this).blur();
   e.preventDefault(); 
});
```