# close select on android navigateur (galaxy tablet)

Tags: android, jquery

I would like to close the select list **when** user choose one option in the list.
Actually, i do it with the following code:

```
jQuery("#selectId").bind("change", function(e) {
    // some stuff

    jQuery(this).blur();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

but it doesn't work on my **galaxy tablet**
thanks a lot

edit: some similars questions waer asked here [how to automatically close mobile select box when an option change event is fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899330/how-to-automatically-close-mobile-select-box-when-an-option-change-event-is-fire) or [Android 4, how to close select panel on change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318414/android-4-how-to-close-select-panel-on-change-event)

Comment: it is the galaxy tab S3? I found with my project that uses communication via socket, that this model has a serious problems in network communication, I think a bug, while on other models of tablet or smartphone does not happen. For my project there was no solution, it was worth, I changed my tablet.

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1". Unfortunately, we couldn't change to another model for this moment (and i have no another one android device for test this problem). On my iphone/ipad perso, it works well!

Comment: you have triee to put before  e.preventDefault(); ane later the blur() function?

Comment: yeah, i have tried it.

Comment: You can try a focusout() function ,try the example directly with your galaxy tab here: http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: it doesn't work. i tried here http://jsfiddle.net/dsea/ZnbPg/4/